# CloudBlockBlob.PutBlockAsync giving error: System.InvalidOperationException: The length of the stream exceeds the permitted length

Tags: c#, .net, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, memorystream

I am trying to upload a large collection of objects in chunks using `CloudBlockBlob.PutBlockAsync` method.
While calling the method, I am getting `System.InvalidOperationException: The length of the stream exceeds the permitted length.`

I verified separately that the memory stream itself for a chunk is not giving OOM or any other errors. (i.e. chunk object is fitting in a memory stream). Is there any stream size limit for the `CloudBlockBlob.PutBlockAsync` method ?
I could not find it in any documentation. I am using `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage 9.3.2 for .Net 4.5`

Below is the code snippet:
(It works in test environments where data is very less, but it breaks in production)

```
foreach (IList<MyDTO> chunk in chunkedDTOs)
{
   
    string blockId = Convert.ToBase64String(Guid.NewGuid().ToByteArray());

    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    using (var sw = new StreamWriter(stream))
    using (JsonWriter writer = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
    {
        var serializer = JsonSerializer.Create();
        serializer.Serialize(writer, chunk);
        await sw.FlushAsync();
        stream.Position = 0;

        
        await cloudBlockBlob.PutBlockAsync(blockId, stream, contentMD5: null, accessCondition: null,
            options: null, operationContext: null, cancellationToken);
    }

    blockIds.Add(blockId); // ids collected to commit later
}
```

Error Stack trace :

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The length of the stream exceeds the permitted length.
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Util.StorageAsyncResult`1.End() in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Core\Util\StorageAsyncResult.cs:line 77
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlockBlob.EndPutBlock(IAsyncResult asyncResult) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Blob\CloudBlockBlob.cs:line 2079
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Util.AsyncExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass7.<CreateCallbackVoid>b__5(IAsyncResult ar) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Core\Util\AsyncExtensions.cs:line 121
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
```

Comment: What’s the size of the block you’re trying to upload?

Answer (score 0):

Fount that as the `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage 9.3.2` is a legacy library, it might be supporting 100 MiB per block. As the memory stream was more than this, the request was failing.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/scalability-targets#scale-targets-for-blob-storage
[image]

I reduced the chunk size so that the memory stream size is lesser that 100 MiB, and that worked.
This library was last updated to 9.3.3 on 11/27/2018. So there is no point in updating the references.
https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/

I would later investigate in using the Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob library instead.